# Conditional Regex for multiple matches in a line

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I've got a regex that is responsible for matching the pattern A:B in lines where you might have multiple matches (i.e. "A:B  A: B  A  : B  A:B", etc.)  The problem lies in the complexity of what A represents.

I'm using the regex:

```
\b[\w|\(|\)+]+\s*:(?:(?![\w+]+\s*:).)*
```

to match items in:

```
Data_1: Tutor              Elementary: 10 a F                 Test:   7.87 sips
Turning 1 Data (A Run), Data:    0.0   10.0   10.0   17.3    0.0
Turning 2 Data (A Run), Data2:    0.0    6.8    0.0    6.8    6.8
Data_1: Tutor  Pool:   Data2: A B C
Turning 2 (A Run), ABSOLUTE:     368    337    428      0      2    147
Data_4   : 4AZE    Localization   : 33.14 lat  -86 long
Time: 0.75   Data Scenario: 3121.2
```

The question is this, if you examine this setup (I use https://regex101.com/), lines 2,3,5 don't return exactly what I'm looking for.  Where the match is the first in the line, I want it to grab everything from the beginning of the line to the first ':'.  Is this type of conditional regex possible?  I've tried every possible way I could imagine, but I haven't been successful yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just fyi you can save and share regex101 pages https://regex101.com/r/O4JKiI/1

Comment: What exactly are you trying to capture?  Everything up to the first `:` on each line?

Comment: I didn't know you could share the regex pages.  For the most part, I'm trying to capture exactly what the above regex captures -- except for the first match of the line.  The regex that gives me the desired result for the first mach is: 
`^([\w|\(|\),\s]*)\s*:(?:(?![\w+]+\s*:).)*`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/nggSBT/1 is the link for the example in the last comment.

Comment: I think it might be helpful to have a little more context.  What data are you trying to extract from the text you have?  Your regexs are a little over complex and hard to read, so it would be very helpful if you could describe it in words.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.   I'll see if I can break it down:
Match 1:  All text from the beginning of the line until the word before the second ':'
Match 2-n:  All text including the word immediately preceding the ':' until either the end of the line or the word before the next ':'

I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: What do you do for lines with fewer than two `:`?

Comment: Just take the first match.  You'd basically be reading in the whole line, in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little complex, but try this [here](https://regex101.com/r/nggSBT/3)

```
^(.*?:.*?)(\b\w+\b\s*:.*?)\b\w+\b:.*$|^(.*?:.*?)\b\w+\b\s*:(.*?)$|^(.*)$
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  This worked perfectly.  I've been banging my head on this for three days.  I'm obviously new to Regex, but I'm determined to learn it.  Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: @PilotGuy don't beat yourself up too much, this was a pretty complex one.  The trick is basically smushing together three regexes for two+ `:`s, one `:` and no `:`s